# date not being compared in sql server 2000

Tags: sql-server, vb.net

I have `FrmDt` and `ToDt` as datetime column in sql server2000. I am comparing dates in these columns with two datetimepicker like this-
SQL query :

```
SqlCmd = New SqlCommand("SELECT DISTINCT AllwnsDedId FROM vwGetEmpCntrctWisePaymnt 
WHERE Type=1 AND Emp_ID='" & txtEmpID.Text & "' 
AND FrmDt>='" & dtp1dtp1.Value.Date & "' AND ToDt<='" & dtp2dtp1.Value.Date & "'", Sqlconn)
```

In Query Analyzer, I tried :

`FrmDt>='01/21/2015' AND ToDt<='01/21/2016'`

Its giving me correct output. But I am not getting the output in Vb.net? Anything missing?

Comment: what is value in FrmDt and ToDt ?

Comment: Even SQL-Server 2000 supports parameters, use them with `SqlDbType.DateTime`.

Comment: Values are dates in dd/MM/yyyy format.

Comment: I am displaying date in two DTPs like 01/Mar/2015.

Comment: @GaziRizwan: `DateTime` has no _format_, it just has a value. You are using strings which may be converted to datetime by the database. Use the correct type in the first place.

Comment: [You should **ALWAYS** use parameterised queries](http://blog.codinghorror.com/give-me-parameterized-sql-or-give-me-death/). They are typed so avoid conversion errors, you can add your length so avoid truncation errors, they are able to reused cached query plans so save on compilation time, and protect you against SQL injection.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order for this to work reliably you need to use proper Date datatypes. Change your SQL to something like;

```
WHERE FrmDt>=@FrmDt AND ToDt<=@ToDt
```

then add 2 paramater objects to the command, one for each date. Your code should end up something like this;

```
SqlCmd = New SqlCommand("SELECT DISTINCT AllwnsDedId FROM vwGetEmpCntrctWisePaymnt 
WHERE Type=1 AND Emp_ID='" & txtEmpID.Text & "' 
AND FrmDt>=@FrmDt AND ToDt<=@ToDt", Sqlconn)

SqlCmd.Parameters.Add("@FrmDt", SqlDbType.DateTime).Value = dtp1dtp1.Value.Date
SqlCmd.Parameters.Add("@ToDt", SqlDbType.DateTime).Value = dtp2dtp1.Value.Date
```

Comment: Helped Dear. Thank you so much for the efforts taken to solve the problem dear Rhys Jones and thanks other members too for helping and considering the problem.